# selectedOption is getting undefined and navigating back to default value of select tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu

I am taking option details from GroupsToPageMapping.tsx for option details which I am getting from API call using redux. In this Navigation file, When I am selecting a value from dropdown, the selectedOption for few nanoseconds grabs that value and then becomes undefined and coming back to it's default value.

I have though that option state is getting changed again and again that is why it is happening, but for default value it is working fine. Not getting where is the issue.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppDispatch } from '../../redux/store';
import GroupsToPagesMapping from "../GroupToPageMapping/GroupToPageMapping";
import { replayAccess } from "../../redux/reducers/ReplayAccessSlice";

function Navigation({currentRoute, setCurrentRoute }: { currentRoute:any,setCurrentRoute: any }) {
 
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<any>();
  const [option, setOption] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const selectIntegrationRef = useRef<any>();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const customStyles = {
    control: (styles: any) => ({
      ...styles,
      fontSize: "14px",
      width: "140px",
    }),

    option: (styles: any, { isSelected }: any) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: isSelected ? "#fff" : "#002856",
      fontSize: "14px",
    }),

    singleValue: (styles: any) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: "black",
      fontSize: "14px",
      fontWeight: "500",
    }),

    placeholder: (styles: any) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: "black",
      fontSize: "14px",
      fontWeight: "500",
    }),

    menu: (styles: any) => ({
      ...styles,
      background: "rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.95)",
      border: "0.5px solid #D9E3EC",
      boxShadow: "0px 2px 3px rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.25)",
      borderRadius: "2px",
      zIndex:"2"
    }),
  };

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if(option?.length > 0){
  //     setSelectedOption(option[0]);
  //     navigate(`/${option[0]?.['value']}`);
  //   }
  // }, []);

  const handleChange = (data: any) => { 
      setSelectedOption(data);
      setCurrentRoute(data.value);
      navigate(`/${data.value}`);
  };


    console.log("see -> ", selectedOption);


    const handleCallBack = (mappingState : any) => {
        setOption(mappingState);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(replayAccess(selectedOption?.writeAccess));
    }, [selectedOption]);

    return (
      <>
      <GroupsToPagesMapping onCallBack={handleCallBack}/>
      <div className="integration">
        <div>Integration</div>
        {option?.length > 0 && (<Select
          styles={customStyles}
          ref={selectIntegrationRef}
          defaultValue={() => {
            navigate(`/${option[0]?.['value']}`);
            return option[0];
          }}
          options={option}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={selectedOption}
          menuPortalTarget={document.body}
          menuPlacement="auto"
          menuPosition="fixed"
        />)}
      </div>
      </>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).